# Error occurs while calculating the pearson values of two rows: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pearson-correlation

i want to calculate the pearson correlation coefficient of two rows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
data = pd.read_csv("result2.csv")


USER = data.iloc[:,0:16370].values
arr =np.array(USER[0]).tostring()
arr2 =np.array(USER[1]).tostring()
print(arr)
vla = pearsonr(arr, arr2)
print(vla)
```

in CSV file I have 100 users(`user_id` being one column) and 16370 columns wise (`product_id`)   I want to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient.

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| user_id         |  B004MYH08U |  B000BNXDBO | 783229135 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A11L5M4MJP00UW | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A13NO1WIGJZUV4 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A141HP4LYPWMSR | 1           | 4           | 4         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A14HV65O34S8EF | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A174WE983H06N4 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A17RUD7RKGZUA4 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A18758S1PUYIDT | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A19O5ETNRJN39D | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1AFHYBINSG7PH | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1CIW2OEVAJRM2 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1D12NAC1U12F0 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1DDVFGUC6NQD3 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1DZ4MTJY8LAVG | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1FRPGQYQTAOR1 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1I7QGUDP043DG | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1J50B4K22D93F | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1M3W0ROKC7F3C | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1M5405JH9THP9 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1MIFONBFK8OWE | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1MXSUEA3ZK5UZ | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1NN07FHTQZZ6K | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1OUBOGB5970AO | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1R6DF0KOJ0TG6 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1RSDE90N6RSZF | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A1VJCDRXUQVXBM | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A23Q1T4MXZHFM7 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A245OASCPKPJHC | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2582KMXLK2P06 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A27H9DOUGY9FOS | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2942G3FDOIM18 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A295JWKTJLM7YT | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A29DLKCN8QWO7B | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2BTR8ZO8MB01D | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2D595HNMO9PHR | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2DLKD4AC5JV5Q | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2FX6OHBMQ9545 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2H5D7IK9SF07M | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2I6MHMAZZDCRX | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2IMLPUXYQJTSY | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2IOMS4TK2QSFW | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2IT3899H776LW | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2M2O1DI1SCQDI | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2M4H4R4Z7UDZX | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2OKCS5234ZV7S | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2ON9S58W4AZ1Z | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2P7UB02HAVEPB | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2R1VN4J5L2ZCO | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2TTVV34NLMZI8 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2TX99AZKDK0V7 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2UFG3DMVELP6I | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2URPOBDQK3WG  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2VDM3D712BGLE | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2WFI5XFB7NHHJ | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A2YWH9COGWT8VU | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A31YQQYX9PU04Z | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A328S9RN3U5M68 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A34KFDQ5KBHZA5 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A36SSF310LBGSE | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A39I79H1A2A8C3 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A39M64IZTC04G0 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3ENN12GLNTUAF | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3GX0UO7XXZST2 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3IG9WGCIHPJ6X | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3N27L13CWJ9HY | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3N2MVBI1A2I9Y | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3NNR95R50VB4W | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3NPHQVIY59Y0Y | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3NWP0SFAC0ZD2 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3Q4S5DFVPB70D | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3QIEISBZP4QTV | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3QYDL5CDNYN66 | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3R95JCH1K9R0S | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3RVH9HUN9J4LZ | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A3VP6XR88INLRB | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A44YJ6ZLTMAR6  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A4FBBS25X3XEL  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A63FDY7VFOMQV  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A66KMXH9V7OGU  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A7LRQFZW3D9NE  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A8DDTUL8OWFMO  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  A9Q28YTLYREO7  | 0           | 3           | 4         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AA72A0AYTWV5Y  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AD4CDZK7D31XP  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AFC8IKR407HSK  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AFJ27ZV9183B8  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AFKMBAY28XO8A  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AH7ZNGM8WOOGN  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AMEJTGF5NQLNH  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  ANZNLFBN62YKH  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AOIT2QUH8GRGA  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AQJVNDW6YZFQS  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  ASES4LU7WKYC   | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  ATK3QFC6L1318  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  ATXL536YX71TR  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AUQW6UEZFC7B2  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AVQRC2N2SSSYS  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AVV8PPI6BDKVA  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AWPODHOB4GFWL  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  AXMKAXC0TR9AW  | 0           | 0           | 0         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**error is:**

```
 TypeError: len() of unsized object
```